# invokeAll() is not willing to accept a Collection<Callable<T>>

Tags: java, executorservice, callable

I fail to understand why this code won't compile

```
ExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(threads);

class DocFeeder implements Callable<Boolean> {....} 
... 
List<DocFeeder> list = new LinkedList<DocFeeder>();
list.add(new DocFeeder(1));
...
executor.invokeAll(list);
```

The error msg is:

```
The method invokeAll(Collection<Callable<T>>) in the type ExecutorService is 
not applicable for the arguments (List<DocFeeder>)
```

`list` is a `Collection` of `DocFeeder`, which implements `Callable<Boolean>` - What is going on?!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just to expand on saua's answer a little...

In Java 5, the method was declared as:

```
invokeAll(Collection<Callable<T>> tasks)
```

In Java 6, the method is declared as:

```
invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
```

The wildcarding difference is very important - because `List<DocFeeder>` *is* a `Collection<? extends Callable<T>>` but it's *not* a `Collection<Callable<T>>`. Consider what would happen with this method:

```
public void addSomething(Collection<Callable<Boolean>> collection)
{
    collection.add(new SomeCallable<Boolean>());
}
```

That's legal - but it's clearly bad if you can call `addSomething` with a `List<DocFeeder>` as it will try to add a non-DocFeeder to the list.

So, if you are stuck with Java 5, you need to create a `List<Callable<Boolean>>` from your `List<DocFeeder>`.

Answer (score 7):

That code compiles perfectly fine with Java 6, but fails to compile with Java 5 giving

```
Foo.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method invokeAll(java.util.List)
location: interface java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
executor.invokeAll(list);
        ^
1 error
```

However changing the `list` like this:

```
Collection<Callable<Boolean>> list = new LinkedList<Callable<Boolean>>();
```

Makes it work on both Java 5 and Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed answer , but it still bugs me - Callable is an interface , so actually , the "addSomething" function in Jon's answer should be OK (not only legal , but reasonable) - because , well , that's the whole point of interfaces - As long as you comply with some initial agreement , I don't care which object you'd add to the list. imo , the problem you presented should be addressed on a different scope.

Besides that , the fact remains that the code didn't compile - and it should have...

Comment: No, it *shouldn't* have compiled (against Java 5) - because of that very variance problem. Basically variance in generics doesn't work the way you expect it to, and shouldn't - it would be dangerous.

Comment: (Of course, they should have declared the method in Java 5 the way they did in Java 6 - the fix applied there is entirely appropriate.)

Comment: The fix is inappropriate because it means you can't cleanly write an ExecutorService for both 1.5 and 1.6. (jsr166_ has appologised for both cockups.)

Comment: @Tom: That's true, but I'd rather have a fix that's compatible on the client side, because there are definitely more people using an ExecutorService than there are people writing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection<Callable<Boolean>> list = new LinkedList<Callable<Boolean>>();
```