# ExecutorService, how to wait for all tasks to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

What is the simplest way to to wait for all tasks of `ExecutorService` to finish? My task is primarily computational, so I just want to run a large number of jobs - one on each core.  Right now my setup looks like this:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
for (DataTable singleTable : uniquePhrases) {   
    es.execute(new ComputeDTask(singleTable));
}
try{
    es.wait();
} 
catch (InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`ComputeDTask` implements runnable.  This appears to execute the tasks correctly, but the code crashes on `wait()` with `IllegalMonitorStateException`.  This is odd, because I played around with some toy examples and it appeared to work.

`uniquePhrases` contains several tens of thousands of elements.  Should I be using another method?  I am looking for something as simple as possible

Answer (score 264):

The simplest approach is to use [`ExecutorService.invokeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) which does what you want in a one-liner.  In your parlance, you'll need to modify or wrap `ComputeDTask` to implement `Callable<>`, which can give you quite a bit more flexibility.  Probably in your app there is a meaningful implementation of `Callable.call()`, but here's a way to wrap it if not using [`Executors.callable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#callable-java.lang.Runnable-).

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
List<Callable<Object>> todo = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>(singleTable.size());

for (DataTable singleTable: uniquePhrases) { 
    todo.add(Executors.callable(new ComputeDTask(singleTable))); 
}

List<Future<Object>> answers = es.invokeAll(todo);
```

As others have pointed out, you could use the timeout version of `invokeAll()` if appropriate.  In this example, `answers` is going to contain a bunch of `Future`s which will return nulls (see definition of `Executors.callable()`.  Probably what you want to do is a slight refactoring so you can get a useful answer back, or a reference to the underlying `ComputeDTask`, but I can't tell from your example.

If it isn't clear, note that `invokeAll()` will not return until all the tasks are completed.   (i.e., all the `Future`s in your `answers` collection will report `.isDone()` if asked.)  This avoids all the manual shutdown, awaitTermination, etc... and allows you to reuse this `ExecutorService` neatly for multiple cycles, if desired.

There are a few related questions on SO:

- [How to wait for all threads to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/java-how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish)
- [Return values from java threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314402/return-values-from-java-threads)
- [invokeAll() not willing to accept a Collection<Callable<t>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370707/invokeall-is-not-willing-to-acept-a-collectioncallablet)
- [Do I need to synchronize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360936/do-i-need-to-synchronize-on-the-result-of-an-invokeall-call)

None of these are strictly on-point for your question, but they do provide a bit of color about how folks think `Executor`/`ExecutorService` ought to be used.

Comment: This is perfect if you're adding all of your jobs in a batch and you hang onto the list of Callables, but it won't work if you're calling ExecutorService.submit() in a callback or event-loop situation.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that shutdown() still should be called when the ExecutorService is no longer needed, otherwise the threads will never terminate (except for the cases when corePoolSize=0 or allowCoreThreadTimeOut=true).

Comment: amazing! Just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for sharing the answer. Let me try this out.

Comment: @Desty In such situation, what will be the best way to implement?

Answer (score 67):

If you want to wait for all tasks to complete, use the [`shutdown`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) method instead of `wait`.  Then follow it with [`awaitTermination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

Also, you can use [`Runtime.availableProcessors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors--) to get the number of hardware threads so you can initialize your threadpool properly.

Comment: shutdown() stops the ExecutorService from accepting new tasks and closes down idle worker threads. It is not specified to wait for the shutdown to complete and the implementation in ThreadPoolExecutor does not wait.

Comment: @Alain - thanks.  I should have mentioned awaitTermination.  Fixed.

Comment: What if in order for a task to finish it must schedule further tasks? For example, you could make a multithreaded tree traversal which hands off branches to worker threads. In that case, since the ExecutorService is shut down instantly it fails to accept any recursively scheduled jobs.

Comment: That becomes an interesting problem.  One solution is you could utilize a separate executor service for child tasks only, and not expose it to users.  That might be inefficient though with the additional threads.  It sounds like you might need some more advanced life time management of the executor to determine when it is safe to call shutdown.

Comment: unfortunately after using shutdown, you can never schedule any more tasks, so basically have to new up your ExecutorService again, but it may be worth the trade off...if you have a stopping point where you know you won't be adding any new future threads, that is...

Comment: `awaitTermination` requires timeout time as a parameter. While it's possible to provide a finite time and place a loop around it to wait until all threads have finished, I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: You are right, but see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1250655/263895 - you could always give it an incredibly long timeout

Comment: @NG., at first sight it seems that the `awaitTermination` API is incomplete because of not providing a way to allow to wait indefinitely.

Answer (score 52):

If waiting for all tasks in the `ExecutorService` to finish isn't precisely your goal, but rather waiting until a *specific batch of tasks* has completed, you can use a [`CompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) — specifically, an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).

The idea is to create an `ExecutorCompletionService` wrapping your `Executor`, [submit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) some *known number* of tasks through the `CompletionService`, then draw that *same number* of results from the *completion queue* using either [`take()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#take()) (which blocks) or [`poll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#poll()) (which does not). Once you've drawn all the expected results corresponding to the tasks you submitted, you know they're all done.

Let me state this one more time, because it's not obvious from the interface: You must know how many things you put into the `CompletionService` in order to know how many things to try to draw out. This matters especially with the `take()` method: call it one time too many and it will block your calling thread until some other thread submits another job to the same `CompletionService`.

There are [some examples showing how to use `CompletionService`](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/listings/Renderer.java) in the book [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](http://jcip.net/).

Comment: This is a good counterpoint to my answer -- I'd say the straightforward answer to the question is invokeAll(); but @seh has it right when submitting groups of jobs to the ES and waiting for them to complete...  --JA

Comment: @om-nom-nom, thank you for updating the links. I am glad to see that the answer is still useful.

Comment: Good answer, I wasn't aware of `CompletionService`

Comment: This is the approach to use, if you don't want to shutdown an existing ExecutorService, but just want to submit a batch of tasks, and know when they are all finished.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to wait for the executor service to finish executing, call `shutdown()` and then, [awaitTermination(units, unitType)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), e.g. `awaitTermination(1, MINUTE)`. The ExecutorService does not block on it's own monitor, so you can't use `wait` etc.

Comment: I think it's awaitTermination.

Comment: @SB - Thanks - I see my memory is fallible! I've updated the name and added a link to be sure.

Comment: To wait "forever," use it like `awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);` http://stackoverflow.com/a/1250655/32453

Comment: I think this is the easiest approach

Comment: @MosheElisha, are you sure?. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown-- says _Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted._

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel You are correct. I just tested it also and I believe I was wrong. I will delete my comment so it won't confuse people.

Answer (score 9):

You could wait jobs to finish on a certain interval:

```
int maxSecondsPerComputeDTask = 20;
try {
    while (!es.awaitTermination(uniquePhrases.size() * maxSecondsPerComputeDTask, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        // consider giving up with a 'break' statement under certain conditions
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);    
}
```

Or you could use *ExecutorService*.**submit**(*Runnable*) and collect the *Future* objects that it returns and call **get()** on each in turn to wait for them to finish.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<<Future<?>>();
for (DataTable singleTable : uniquePhrases) {
    futures.add(es.submit(new ComputeDTask(singleTable)));
}
for (Future<?> future : futures) {
   try {
       future.get();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   } catch (ExecutionException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
}
```

*InterruptedException* is extremely important to handle properly.  It is what lets you or the users of your library terminate a long process safely.

Answer (score 8):

Just use

```
latch = new CountDownLatch(noThreads)
```

In each thread

```
latch.countDown();
```

and as barrier

```
latch.await();
```

Comment: Don't forget to catch the InterruptedException while awaiting.

Answer (score 8):

There are several approaches.

You can call first [ExecutorService.shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) and then [ExecutorService.awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) which returns:

> `true` if this executor terminated and `false` if the timeout elapsed
> before termination

So:

> There is a function called `awaitTermination` But a timeout has to be
> provided in it. Which is not a guarantee that when this returns all
> the tasks would have been finished. Is there a way to achieve this?

You just have to call `awaitTermination` in a loop.

**Using `awaitTermination`:**

A full example of this implementation:

```
public class WaitForAllToEnd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int total_threads = 4;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(total_threads);
        for(int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++){
            executor.execute(parallelWork(100 + i * 100));
        }

        int count = 0;

        // This is the relevant part
        // Chose the delay most appropriate for your use case
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            System.out.println("Waiting "+ count);
            count++;
        }
    }

    private static Runnable parallelWork(long sleepMillis) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Do Something
            }
            System.out.println("I am Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        };
    }
}
```

**Using `CountDownLatch`:**

Another option is to create a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with a `count` equal to the number of parallel tasks. Each thread calls `countDownLatch.countDown();`, while the *main* thread calls `countDownLatch.await();`.

A full example of this implementation:

```
public class WaitForAllToEnd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int total_threads = 4;
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(total_threads);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(total_threads);
        for(int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++){
            executor.execute(parallelWork(100 + i * 100, countDownLatch));
        }
        countDownLatch.await();
        System.out.println("Exit");
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private static Runnable parallelWork(long sleepMillis, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Do Something
            }
            System.out.println("I am Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        };
    }
}
```

**Using `CyclicBarrier`:**

Another approach is to use a [Cyclic Barrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

```
public class WaitForAllToEnd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
        final int total_threads = 4;
        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(total_threads+ 1);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(total_threads);
        for(int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++){
            executor.execute(parallelWork(100 + i * 100, barrier));
        }
        barrier.await();
        System.out.println("Exit");
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private static Runnable parallelWork(long sleepMillis, CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Do Something
            }
            System.out.println("I am Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            try {
                barrier.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
              // Do something
            }
        };
    }
}
```

There are other approaches as well but those would require changes to your initial requirements, namely:

> How to wait for all tasks to be completed when they are submitted
> using  ExecutorService.execute() .

Answer (score 7):

Root cause for [IllegalMonitorStateException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

From your code, you have just called wait() on ExecutorService without owning the lock.

Below code will fix `IllegalMonitorStateException`

```
try 
{
    synchronized(es){
        es.wait(); // Add some condition before you call wait()
    }
}
```

Follow one of below approaches to wait for completion of all tasks, which have been submitted to `ExecutorService`.

1. Iterate through all `Future` tasks from `submit` on `ExecutorService` and check the status with blocking call `get()` on `Future` object
2. Using [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) on `ExecutorService`
3. Using [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)
4. Using [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) or [newWorkStealingPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool--) of `Executors`(since java 8)
5. Shutdown the pool as recommended in oracle documentation [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

   ```
   void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
      pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
      try {
      // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
      if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
          pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
          // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
          if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
          System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
      }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
        pool.shutdownNow();
        // Preserve interrupt status
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
   ```

   If you want to gracefully wait for all tasks for completion when you are using option 5 instead of options 1 to 4, change

   ```
   if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
   ```

   to

   a `while(condition)` which checks for every 1 minute.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ExecutorService.invokeAll` method, It will execute all task and wait till all threads finished their task.

Here is complete [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection))

You can also user overloaded version of this method to specify the timeout.

Here is sample code with `ExecutorService.invokeAll`

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        List<Callable<String>> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        taskList.add(new Task1());
        taskList.add(new Task2());
        List<Future<String>> results = service.invokeAll(taskList);
        for (Future<String> f : results) {
            System.out.println(f.get());
        }
    }

}

class Task1 implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            return "Task 1 done";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return " error in task1";
        }
    }
}

class Task2 implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            return "Task 2 done";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return " error in task2";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also have the situation that I have a set of documents to be crawled. I start with an initial "seed" document which should be processed, that document contains links to other documents which should also be processed, and so on.

In my main program, I just want to write something like the following, where `Crawler` controls a bunch of threads.

```
Crawler c = new Crawler();
c.schedule(seedDocument); 
c.waitUntilCompletion()
```

The same situation would happen if I wanted to navigate a tree; i would pop in the root node, the processor for each node would add children to the queue as necessary, and a bunch of threads would process all the nodes in the tree, until there were no more.

I couldn't find anything in the JVM which I thought was a bit surprising. So I wrote a class `ThreadPool` which one can either use directly or subclass to add methods suitable for the domain, e.g. `schedule(Document)`. Hope it helps!

[ThreadPool Javadoc](https://javadoc.databasesandlife.com/com/databasesandlife/util/ThreadPool.html) | [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databasesandlife/java-common)

Comment: Doc Link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Add all threads in collection and submit it using `invokeAll`.
If you can use `invokeAll` method of `ExecutorService`, JVM won’t proceed to next line until all threads are complete.

Here there is a good example:
[invokeAll via ExecutorService](http://jovialjava.blogspot.com.tr/2011/01/part-7-javautilconcurrent-invokeall-via.html)

Answer (score 1):

Submit your tasks into the **Runner** and then wait calling the method **waitTillDone()** like this:

```
Runner runner = Runner.runner(2);

for (DataTable singleTable : uniquePhrases) {

    runner.run(new ComputeDTask(singleTable));
}

// blocks until all tasks are finished (or failed)
runner.waitTillDone();

runner.shutdown();
```

To use it add this gradle/maven dependency: `'com.github.matejtymes:javafixes:1.0'`

For more details look here: https://github.com/MatejTymes/JavaFixes or here: http://matejtymes.blogspot.com/2016/04/executor-that-notifies-you-when-task.html

Answer (score 0):

I will just wait for the executor to terminate with a specified timeout that you think  it is suitable for the tasks to complete.

```
 try {  
         //do stuff here 
         exe.execute(thread);
    } finally {
        exe.shutdown();
    }
    boolean result = exe.awaitTermination(4, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    if (!result)

    {
        LOGGER.error("It took more than 4 hour for the executor to stop, this shouldn't be the normal behaviour.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [`ForkJoinPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) and use the global pool to execute tasks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // the default `commonPool` should be sufficient for many cases.
    ForkJoinPool pool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool(); 
    // The root of your task that may spawn other tasks. 
    // Make sure it submits the additional tasks to the same executor that it is in.
    Runnable rootTask = new YourTask(pool); 
    pool.execute(rootTask);
    pool.awaitQuiescence(...);
    // that's it.
}
```

The beauty is in `pool.awaitQuiescence` where the method will block utilize the caller's thread to execute its tasks and then return when it is *really* empty.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```java
Object lock = new Object();
CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(threadNum);
for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++) {
    executorService.execute(() -> {

        synchronized (lock) {
            cdl.countDown();
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    });
}
cdl.await();
synchronized (lock) {
    lock.notifyAll();
}
```

if you do not add new tasks to ExecutorService , this may wait for all current tasks completed

Answer (score -1):

A simple alternative to this is to use threads along with join.
Refer : [Joining Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908515/java-how-to-use-thread-join)

Comment: ExecutorServices makes things simpler

Answer (score -2):

you can use this :

```
while (!executors.isTerminated()){}
```

Comment: Don't do this. This is a busy loop which will waste CPU time. An `ExecutorService` has the [`awaitTermination` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) for a reason, use that.