# how to deal with multiple worker threads that may create new work items

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a queue that contains work items and I want to have multiple threads work in parallel on those items. **When a work item is processed it may result in new work items.** The problem I have is that I can't find a solution on how to determine if I'm done. The worker looks like that:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      WorkItem item = queue.nextItem();
      if (item != null) {
        processItem(item);
      }
      else {
        // the queue is empty, but there may still be other workers
        // processing items which may result in new work items
        // how to determine if the work is completely done?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This seems like a pretty simple problem actually but I'm at a loss. What would be the best way to implement that?

thanks

clarification:
**The worker threads have to terminate once none of them is processing an item, but as long as at least one of them is still working they have to wait because it may result in new work items.**

Comment: Usually you would wait on some kind of sync object, that is notified whenever a new item is added to the queue.

Answer (score 3):

What about using an ExecutorService which will allow you to wait for all tasks to finish: [ExecutorService, how to wait for all tasks to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269445/executorservice-how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-to-finish)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest wait/notify calls. In the else case, your worker threads would wait on an object until notified by the queue that there is more work to do. When a worker creates a new item, it adds it to the queue, and the queue calls notify on the object the workers are waiting on. One of them will wake up to consume the new item.

> The methods wait, notify, and notifyAll of class Object support an efficient transfer of control from one thread to another. Rather than simply "spinning" (repeatedly locking and unlocking an object to see whether some internal state has changed), which consumes computational effort, a thread can suspend itself using wait until such time as another thread awakens it using notify. This is especially appropriate in situations where threads have a producer-consumer relationship (actively cooperating on a common goal) rather than a mutual exclusion relationship (trying to avoid conflicts while sharing a common resource).

[Source: Threads and Locks](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/memory.doc.html)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. But when all the workers are waiting there won't be any more work so in that case I would need to exit the loop. And precisely that is my problem, i.e. I need the threads to terminate once none of them is working.

Comment: Interesting. The queue will need to know about the state of all the workers. I would replace the while(true) line with a while(!queue.workComplete()). Whenever a new item is requested and there is currently no new work, have the queue check the state of the workers. If they all report that they've completed their tasks, return true for workComplete(), and then call NotifyAll on the object the workers wait on. They'll all wake up, find out there's no more work coming, and terminate. Might be some synch trickery to deal with, but I'm fairly certain it could work.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds viable, I will think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at something higher level than wait/notify. It's very difficult to get right and avoid deadlocks. Have you looked at `java.util.concurrent.CompletionService<V>`? You could have a simpler manager thread that polls the service and `take()`s the results, which may or may not contain a new work item.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) containing items to process along with a synchronized set that keeps track of all elements being processed currently:

```
BlockingQueue<WorkItem> bQueue;
Set<WorkItem> beingProcessed = new Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashMap<WorkItem>());
bQueue.put(workItem);
...

// the following runs over many threads in parallel
while (!(bQueue.isEmpty() && beingProcessed.isEmpty())) {
  WorkItem currentItem = bQueue.poll(50L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // null for empty queue
  if (currentItem != null) {
    beingProcessed.add(currentItem);   
    processItem(currentItem); // possibly bQueue.add(newItem) is called from processItem
    beingProcessed.remove(currentItem);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: as @Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggested, an `ExecutorService` is probably what you should really use.  You can add new tasks as you go along. You can semi-busy wait for termination of all tasks at regular interval with `executorService.awaitTermination(time, timeUnits)` and kill all your threads after that.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Unfortunately I can't upvote due to low rep.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the beginnings of a queue to solve your problem.  bascially, you need to track new work *and* in process work.

```
public class WorkQueue<T> {
    private final List<T> _newWork = new LinkedList<T>();
    private int _inProcessWork;

    public synchronized void addWork(T work) {
        _newWork.add(work);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized T startWork() throws InterruptedException {
        while(_newWork.isEmpty() && (_inProcessWork > 0)) {
            wait();
            if(!_newWork.isEmpty()) {
                _inProcessWork++;
                return _newWork.remove(0);
            }
        }
        // everything is done
        return null;
    }

    public synchronized void finishWork() {
        _inProcessWork--;
        if((_inProcessWork == 0) && _newWork.isEmpty()) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

your workers will look roughly like:

```
public class Worker {
  private final WorkQueue<T> _queue;

  public void run() {
    T work = null;
    while((work = _queue.startWork()) != null) {
      try {
        // do work here...
      } finally {
        _queue.finishWork();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the one trick is that you need to add the first work item _before you start any workers (otherwise they will all immediately exit).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, this looks pretty good. Unfortunately I can't upvote yet.