# Multithreaded approach using java Executor interface

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to implement the multithreaded approach using executor interface where i have produced multiple threads in main class

```
class Main
{
    private static final int NTHREADS = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        .........
        String str = createThreads(document);
        .............
    }


    public String createThreads(String docString)
    {

        ........
        .......
        Map<String,String> iTextRecords = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        if(!iText.matches(""))
        {
            String[] tokenizedItext = iText.split("\\^");
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS);
            for(int index = 0 ;index < tokenizedItext.length;index++)
            {
                Callable<Map<String,String>> worker = null;
                Future<Map<String,String>> map = null;
                if(tokenizedItext[index].matches("^[0-9.<>+-= ]+$") || tokenizedItext[index].matches("^\\s+$"))
                {
                    iTextRecords.put(tokenizedItext[index],tokenizedItext[index]);
                }
                else
                {
                    worker = new MultipleDatabaseCallable(tokenizedItext[index],language);
                    map = executor.submit(worker);
                    try
                    {
                        iTextRecords.putAll(map.get());
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }
                    catch(ExecutionException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }
                }

            }

            executor.shutdown();
            // Wait until all threads are finish
            while (!executor.isTerminated())
            {

            }

    }
}
```

The Callable class is as

```
class MultipleDatabaseCallable implements Callable<Map<String,String>> 
{
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> call() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Entering: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(int i =0;i<50000;i++)
        {
            for(int i1 = 0 ;i1<5000;i1++)
            {
                for(int i2 =0;i2 <500;i2++)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return map;
    }
}
```

output I am getting is

```
Entering: pool-1-thread-1
Exiting: pool-1-thread-1
Entering: pool-1-thread-2
Exiting: pool-1-thread-2
Entering: pool-1-thread-3
Exiting: pool-1-thread-3
Entering: pool-1-thread-4
Exiting: pool-1-thread-4
Entering: pool-1-thread-5
Exiting: pool-1-thread-5
Entering: pool-1-thread-6
Exiting: pool-1-thread-6
```

While looking at the output it seems like only one thread is entering at a time in the call method and other thread enters only when previous one exist. However it is expected that the multiple threads should enter and execute call() method. Also when I am executing the same program by making NTHREADS = 1. it is taking same time as it is taking with NTHREADS =10

so it seems like the application is running as good as a single threaded application.please suggest whats wrong i am doing in implementation.

Thanks

Comment: I guess the workload is too low. Your for-loops will be optimized away if you do not do anything in it. Put a Thread.sleep(1) into the innermost loop and test again.

Comment: I tried with that too and the program goes on halt until the thread1 exits

Comment: `iTextRecords.putAll(map.get());` is like join until data available.

Comment: A side note: You should try to avoid `while (!executor.isTerminated()){}`  Because you do busy waiting. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269445/executorservice-how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-to-finish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call

```
                map = executor.submit(worker);
```

the value returned `map` in this case is a `Future`. Meaning that it does not have a value, until the callable has returned one. Now when you call

```
                    iTextRecords.putAll(map.get());
```

What happens is that the current thread blocks (inside the `map.get()`) waiting for the callable to return (in the other thread).

Since you always wait for a callable to be finished (per `map.get()`) before submitting a new one (per `executor.submit()`) you enforce the sequential execution you observe.

In order to execute the tasks in parallel, you have to start them all before calling get for the first time. You could for instance create an `ArrayList<Future<Map<String,String>>> futures = ...` and then 
do

```
  futures.add(executor.submit(worker));
```

to submit the tasks (no need for the `map` variable) and create a second loop (after the `for(int i ...)` loop):

```
 for(Future<Map<String,String>> f: futures) {
     iTextRecords.putAll(f.get);
 }
```

Comment: Missed the get ... +1

Comment: So is there any way to execute multiple threads when you want to get the return values?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain how to collect the return values.

Comment: thanks that thing worked..but in my case the number of iteration will go up to several thousand increasing the array list size to give OutOfMewmoryException and garbageCollector overhead exception.

Comment: True. In this case: add to the iTextRecords (using ConcurrentHashMap instead of the LinkedHashMap) inside the Callables (you can use Runnables instead since you don't need the return value).

Comment: On the other hand, since the FixedThreadPool is using an unbounded queue you have also potentially the problem of waiting Runnables to use up all memory. So you'll either need some method of "controlling" throughput or rethink you design to limit the number of runnables.

Comment: Actually I can't use Runnable because I want each thread to return a value (map)

Comment: I understood that. What I meant was using runnables would be possible if instead of returning you store the data into iTextRecords directly.

Comment: But how can I make values in runnable to be available to iTextRecord in caller class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38244/discussion-between-subsub-and-nishit-jain)

Answer (score 0):

You must collect your futures while you submit the callables. Call get() on your futures only after you finish submitting.