# Why do these Callables never get done?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, callable

I have a code snippet where a loop submits Callable and then checks if these are done and if so print out their Values

```
    ArrayList<Future<ArrayList<String>>> controllList = new  ArrayList<Future<ArrayList<String>>>();
    System.out.println(""+pagecount);
    for(int n=1;n<=pagecount;n++){
        if(controllList.size()<10){
            Future<ArrayList<String>> temp = exeService.submit(new URLSpider("localhost"));
            controllList.add(temp);
        }
        for(int k=0;k<controllList.size();k++){
            if(controllList.get(k).isDone()){
                System.out.println("Something done");
                ArrayList<String> URLs = controllList.get(k).get();
                for(int h=0;h<URLs.size();h++){
                    System.out.println(URLs.get(h));
                }
                controllList.remove(k);
            }
        }
    }
```

URLSpider class:

```
public class URLSpider implements Callable<ArrayList<String>> {
private TagNode node;
private String pageUrl;
private Object[] links;
private ArrayList<String> detailLinks;


public URLSpider(String completePageURL){
    pageUrl = completePageURL;
    detailLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
}
@Override
public ArrayList<String> call() throws Exception {
    HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();

    try {
        node = cleaner.clean(new URL(pageUrl));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        String link;
        links = node.evaluateXPath("some XPath");
        for(int i =0;i<links.length;i++){
            link=((TagNode)links[i]).getAttributeByName("href");
            System.out.println(link); //the code produces URLs as wanted
            detailLinks.add(link);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return detailLinks;
}

}
```

My Problem is that the if statement in the second for-Loop never turns true. I checked if the call method reaches the end. And it did so every  single time. Also the detailURL list ist full of the wanted URLs. But just the isDone() is false all the time.

May somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Read more [ExecutorService, how to wait for all tasks to finish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269445/executorservice-how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-to-finish)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because when you iterate the list, none of the Callables have completed yet.

If you want to block until the Callable is done, you can call `controllList.get(k).get()` - this will block until the task completes.

For your use case you may also look at the [ExecutorCompletionService executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).

Comment: (Y) This is a very good hint I will bear this in mind. But the actuall problem was another. The very outer for-Loop didnt have to run out. So when it could submit a new callable in the first if clause the number n shouldnt increase so that it kept checking in the second for-loop if there is any callable done. Therefore I just had to implement an else statement with n-- ... Shame on me !