# Multithreading with AtomicInteger and ExecutorService not working

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class SynchroExample {

   public final AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger(0);

   private ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

   public void syn() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          service.submit(() -> {
              integer.incrementAndGet();
          });
       }
       service.shutdown();
       System.out.println(integer.get());
   }

   public static void main(String [] args) {
      SynchroExample ex = new SynchroExample();
       ex.syn();
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why this code doesn't work? I was under the impression that AtomicInteger is threadsafe. And this code is not returning 1000.

Comment: `shutdown` is not blocking, it will only prevent any new tasks from been added to the service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AtomicInteger` is thread safe, but you have called `AtomicInteger#get` before all tasks finished. `ExecutorService#shutdown` is not waiting for tasks to finish.

See [`ExecutorService#shutdown` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()):

> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.

Use

```
service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

to wait for all tasks finished.

Comment: Obviously this example is just for proof of concept, but is there any way to shut down the executor service ONLY once all tasks have finished completing? Instead of hardcoding a 10 second time limit?

I also noticed that if I remove the service.shutdown(), this program would still fail (return the wrong number, presumably for the same reason that the tasks have not completed), but the program also hangs forever. Is this because I have hanging threads which have not been terminated?

Comment: Sure, there is lot of ways described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269445/executorservice-how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-to-finish

Comment: Yes, it hangs because uninterrupted threads. `shutdown` method does not interrupt running threads, it only instructs `ExecutorService` to not accept next tasks. `shutdownNow` interrupts threads. There is really nice example of two-phase shutdown in `ExecutorService` javadoc.